# How to remove the characters at the specific column in the entire file skipping the alternative rows?

Tags: notepad++

```
MAN000000020072663428750850204            163026012345678910111    230520190911100412000000000010720000000985019593087174                    223195243                               1000S0100000000000000000000   7946088254                                                                  07
MNA000000030072663428750850099PAYPAL                        AL  JEROZOLIMSKIE 92                  35314369001          PL 61600807          597717979081218228559840
MAN000000040072088653013700204            161936012345678910111    220520190912103025000000000031388000000985019593087174                    PAYPAL                                  1000S0100000000000000000000   7696059646                                                                  07
MNA000000050072088653013700099PAYPAL                     2211 NORTH 1ST STREET                 35314369001          PL 6169352050        7333000000
MAN000000060074197156756790204            186668012345678910111    230920190912110307000000000016019000000985019593087174                    00493056839445                          1000S0100000000000000000000   7448563928                                                                  07
MNA000000070074197156756790099PAYPAL                    ERICH WEINERT STRASSE 145             35314369001          DE 27610409          472222844824087272735760
MAN000000080072694892620830204            111628012345678910111    221020190912111647000000000004115000000985019593087174                    018772238023                            1000S0100000000000000000000   7696043881                                                                  07
MNA000000090072694892620830099PAYPAL                        MR  TREUBLAAN 7                       35314369001          GB 8261097DPNL       412112794272241677955650
MAN000000100074197479926700204            140182012345678910111    240720190912115052000000000022846000000985019593087174                    PAYPAL                                  1000S0100000000000000000000   7448563071                                                                  07
MNA000000110074197479926700099PAYPAL                    2211 NORTH 1ST STREET                 35314369001          PL 6169352050        5641000000
```

I have data like above in Notepad++, I want to remove the numbers from column 43 to 49 in all the file excluding the rows that start with MNA and remove only in the lines containing MAN

ex: It should look like below - Can you also explain the process on how to do

```
MAN000000020072663428750850204            12345678910111    230520190911100412000000000010720000000985019593087174                    223195243                               1000S0100000000000000000000   7946088254                                                                  07
MNA000000030072663428750850099PAYPAL                        AL  JEROZOLIMSKIE 92                  35314369001          PL 61600807          597717979081218228559840
MAN000000040072088653013700204            12345678910111    220520190912103025000000000031388000000985019593087174                    PAYPAL                                  1000S0100000000000000000000   7696059646                                                                  07
MNA000000050072088653013700099PAYPAL                     2211 NORTH 1ST STREET                 35314369001          PL 6169352050        7333000000
MAN000000060074197156756790204            12345678910111    230920190912110307000000000016019000000985019593087174                    00493056839445                          1000S0100000000000000000000   7448563928                                                                  07
MNA000000070074197156756790099PAYPAL                    ERICH WEINERT STRASSE 145             35314369001          DE 27610409          472222844824087272735760
MAN000000080072694892620830204            12345678910111    221020190912111647000000000004115000000985019593087174                    018772238023                            1000S0100000000000000000000   7696043881                                                                  07
MNA000000090072694892620830099PAYPAL                        MR  TREUBLAAN 7                       35314369001          GB 8261097DPNL       412112794272241677955650
MAN000000100074197479926700204            12345678910111    240720190912115052000000000022846000000985019593087174                    PAYPAL                                  1000S0100000000000000000000   7448563071                                                                  07
MNA000000110074197479926700099PAYPAL                    2211 NORTH 1ST STREET                 35314369001          PL 6169352050        5641000000
```

Comment: This site is for **programming/coding** question, You are looking for a guide/tutorial on how to use `Notepad++`. Please take a look on [Notepad++ community website](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org)

Comment: I've done a rollback because your edit doesn't make sense. If you have another question then ask a  new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?!MNA).{42}\K.{7}`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  (?!MNA)       # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't MNA
  .{42}         # 42 any characters 
  \K            # forget all we have seen until this position(i.e. skip all lines before the first occurrence of F 180.0)
 .{7}           # 7 any characters
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]